# Dependency Injection with Ninject share same objects with different instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

I've been gifted having had to work with an already set up Ninject DI based application which I have grown and added to considerably over the development of an application I'm working on.

I now find a problem that I would like to correct. I've managed to work around it using inheritance but would like a more cleaner solution.

I have two connections required to be injected into different services and repositories. I then need the repositories to also be correctly linked to the correct service having the same `UnitOfWork`.

I think I might be asking something that is not possible without inheritance and specialisation but that is why I am asking.

I managed to resolve this by creating a sub class of the main `Repository` and `UnitOfWork` classes but does nothing apart from implementing the base class. 
I just don't like the idea of a sub class that is fully dependant on the super class functionality with basically empty braces apart from constructor, to me this doesn't seem true OOP just to resolve this problem. So I sought for a better solution utilising a one class solution if possible in DI.

So if you can ignore the solution I have spoken about because I completely reverted the change this is what I am left with:

Looking at the code below you can see what is the objective.

```
...

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("UnitOfWork");
    public DbContext DataContext { get; set; }

    public UnitOfWork(string connectionString)
    {
        DataContext = new DbContext(connectionString);
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public IUnitOfWork unitOfWork { get; set; }
    private readonly IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    //private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("Repository");

    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        dbSet = this.unitOfWork.DataContext.Set<T>();
    }
    ...
}
...

public class IPOPDataModules : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
    Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOP_BE_TESTEntities"].ConnectionString);
    Bind<IRepository<tOrder>>().To<Repository<tOrder>>().InRequestScope();
    }
}

...

public class DataModules : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
    Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOP_BAPSEntities"].ConnectionString);
    Bind<IRepository<Data.Quote>>().To<Repository<Data.Quote>>().InRequestScope();
    }
}

...

public class QuoteService : IQuoteService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IRepository<Data.Quote> quoteRepository;
    public QuoteService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<Data.Quote> quoteRepository)
    {
        ...
    }
}

...

public class IPOPService : IIPOPService
{
    private IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    private IRepository<Data.tOrder> tOrderRepository;

    public IPOPService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IRepository<Data.tOrder>)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What I want to know is, is it possible to share the same `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` objects by two different connections and have them injected as different instances to the respective services (`IPOPService` for IPOP_BE_TEST connection, `QuoteService` for IPOP_BAP connection)

Again the code above doesn't achieve want I want but this is the sort of architecture I would like to play around to get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for are Ninject binding scopes. Whenever you declare a binding Ninject will provide a delegate to that binding that the activation process uses to determine if it should create a new instance of that service, or if it should return a previously constructed instance.

So, if you want to implement a singleton in Ninject, you simply declare a binding that looks like this:

```
Bind<IRepository<Data.Quote>>().To<Repository<Data.Quote>>().InSingletonScope();
```

`InSingletonScope()` and `InRequestScope()` are simply sugar (or in the case of `InRequestScope` an extension method) on `IBindingInSyntax<T>` for the `InScope(Func<Ninject.Activation.IContext, object> scope)` method though. Any time you want to ensure that Ninject returns the same instance of a service in a given situation, all you need to do is implement a custom scope.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to ensure that when a request hits your application the same instances of `Repository<T>` and `IUnitOfWork` will be injected into all the services in your application. In this case you would simply have to write bindings like this:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOP_BE_TESTEntities"].ConnectionString);
Bind<IRepository<tOrder>>().To<Repository<tOrder>>().InRequestScope();
```

However, your problem appears to be that you have two separate modules, with two separate bindings. I would suggest that you need to use a single module with contextual binding to determine which connection string should be provided to which part of the system. So your one module might look like this:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
    .To<UnitOfWork>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IIPOPService>()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOP_BE_TESTEntities"].ConnectionString);
Bind<IUnitOfWork>()
    .To<UnitOfWork>()
    .WhenInjectedInto<IQuoteService>()
    .InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("connectionString", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IPOP_BAPSEntities"].ConnectionString);

Bind<IRepository<tOrder>>().To<Repository<tOrder>>().InRequestScope();
```

This way you can be sure that when Ninject is resolving `IIPOPService` it will create an instance of `UnitOfWork` initialized with the `"IPOP_BE_TESTEntities"` connection string, and when resolving `IQuoteService`, it will use the `"IPOP_BAPSEntities"` connection string, but otherwise, across that request scope, only a single instance will be constructed by Ninject.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @s3raph86, unfortunately there are some 40 odd services similar to IIPOPService and IQuoteService and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution if possible to accommodate for all with minimum code changes as possible.

Comment: That shouldn't be a dealbreaker @Saleh - Ninject provides a lot of options for contextual binding. What can you tell me about the rules that you'll need to use when deciding to apply one connection string or the other? Possibly you could define an attribute to decorate your services with, and then use that in your bindings?

Comment: At the moment the app supports 3 conns and more in future (question above shows example of 2). I'm not sure if it's possible, with minimum code changes I want to specify a UnitOfWork with a conn to say `IPOP_BAPS` to a number of repositories and services and at the same time specify another UnitOfWork with a different conn to another set of repositories and services. Also because repositories are injected into services the UnitOfwork in the service and repository it is inserted into need to be the same. The services are not required to be reused but the repositories I would like to reuse.

Comment: Definitely doable. I'll revisit my answer once I've had a chance to tinker and test.

Comment: Keep in mind @Saleh that you may run into issues with disposed UnitOfWork objects if you want to reuse them across your request scope.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sort of new to Ninject in terms of hands on experience and didn't touch much on defining decorator attributes for reuse on services.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand why there will be issues with disposed UnitOfWork?

Comment: Ninject won't automatically detect if you've disposed of your UnitOfWork, so it'll keep on serving the same disposed instance as long as the scope is still current.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not completely clear for me. But check the documentation for the following two scopes, which might be interesting for your scenario.

- `InCallScope` will result that only one instance will be created per resolution tree. I usually use this scope on desktop applications for a unit of work. See the documentation [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope/wiki/InCallScope). You'll need the `Ninject.Extensions.NamedScope` extension for this.
- `InRequestScope` will result that in a web application, only one instance will be created per HTTP request. I usually use this scope for a unit of work. See the documentation [here](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope). You'll need the `Ninject.Web.Common` package for this.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Zoltan, I'm working on an MVC site and I've made some alterations to the question which hopefully should address some confusion caused. Regarding the answer above I want to be able to somehow map the correct `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` (with the correct db connections) to the two different services above. I think I'm missing some Ninject logic that might if possible do the thing.